# Automatically scrolling down to next UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

In my view controller, I have 5 `UITextField` that each take it different data wether from the keyboard or from a `UIPicker`. All of my different elements are in a subclass of a scrollview called `scrollView`. All my first responders have a toolbar as their `inputAccessoryView` with the prev/ next/ done buttons, and they work just fine.

The problem that I am having is that I cannot get the scroll to automatically scroll down to the next `UITextField` (whichever may be) becomes `firstResponder`  to give it enough space to look decent, please refer to this screen shot for reference: 
[image]

I gave this code a try to try to obtain that scroll I am looking for but no luck so far...

```
- (void)keyboardControls:(BSKeyboardControls *)keyboardControls selectedField:(UIView *)field inDirection:(BSKeyboardControlsDirection)direction
{
    UIView *view = keyboardControls.activeField.superview.superview;
    [self.scroller scrollRectToVisible:view.frame animated:YES];
}
```

Here is my simple `scroller` code:

```
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 520)];
```

If you can see the problem that I am having or know a better way to go around this all together please let me know...Your help is really appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: Are you able to scroll by touch?  You need to either shrink your scroll view to the new smaller frame or increase the content size by the height of the keyboard.

Comment: Don't use `scrollToRect`, this will only work if your rect is out of screen, use `contentOffset` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Comment: See Apple's document on [Keyboard Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), in particular the section labeled "Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the textFields in tableView cells. Then the view will scroll down automatically.